# How to Show/Hide Action Bar item programmatically via Click Event

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

By default I set the visibility to false by using following code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
       menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
```

Now how can I make it visible again when user clicks a button in my activity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
       if (hideIcon){
          menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(false);
       }else{
          menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(true);
       }
        return true;
    }
```

In method where you want to show/hide the icon, just set the boolean hideIcon to true or false and call :

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

to refresh the menu.

Answer (score 1):

get the instance of that menu item, and you can set its item Visibility every time.

```
        Menu mMenu;
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
           mMenu = menu;
           mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(false);
           return true;
        }

//somewhere else

mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(true);
```

and based on @chol answer call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Answer (score 0):

While you can create a class field

```
   private Menu menu;
```

and capture its value in onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
   this.menu = menu;
```

Then Write the code in clickListener

```
   this.menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(true);
```